# Are helpful articles involving long history not ON-TOPIC on HSM?

Tags: discussion

I recently completed reading most of the important parts of Papers involving philosophy of atomism and wrote a summary of major Events into my notes which gives pretty fair idea of what and how did people actually thought about "Atoms" earlier, I Wanted To share It on HSM as I found It very useful and document It using HSM, here is the question [A summary of Major events in Pre-Modern Atomist Philosophy of Chemistry](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/15865/17776)   and I answered it myself, The question was closed as being off topic, But I cannot find any policy regarding such question on HSM, the closest I can get is here:https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective ,It states the difference between good subjective and bad subjective questions, Though the question and answer will still be visible, the information will anyways remain documented, I just want to ask about its state of being off topic

Comment: Nowhere in the title or body did you include a question mark, much less a question.

Comment: @JonCuster,Yes,But I really found it fascinating,And Wanted to Document it Collectively,I read HSE policies,And It promotes such things,Maybe,It will help someone in future